# How do I suppress the filter on just one column in DT?

Tags: r, r-markdown, dt

I'm using `DT` to render a datatable from a CSV. One field contains URLs, which are super unwieldy to search within. I'd like to either disable filtering on the URL column or allow searching on whether or not the column has any data (so is there a link or not?)

I'm not even sure where I'd start restricting filters to only some columns. I thought may be adding `targets = c(0,1)` to the filter call would work but it didn't have any impact.

This is what I have now:

```r
mydf <- data.frame(
  name=c("ABC","DEF","GHI","","MNO","PQR"), 
  value=1000:1005, 
  link=c("https://www.example.com/abc", "https://www.example.com/def", "https://www.example.com/ghi","https://www.example.com/jkl", "https://www.example.com/mno", "https://www.example.com/pqr"))

datatable(mydf, options = list(columnDefs = list(
  list(targets = 2, render = JS(
      "function(data, type, full, meta) {",
      "return type === 'display' ?",
      "'<a href=\"'+data+'\">linq</a>' : data;",
      "}")),
  list(targets = c(0,1), className = 'dt-center'),
  list(targets = 2, className = 'dt-right')
  )),
  rownames = FALSE,
  filter = list(position = 'bottom', clear = FALSE))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add `searchable = FALSE` for the specific column.

```
DT::datatable(mydf, options = list(columnDefs = list(
  list(targets = 2, render = JS(
      "function(data, type, full, meta) {",
      "return type === 'display' ?",
      "'<a href=\"'+data+'\">linq</a>' : data;",
      "}")),
  list(className = 'dt-center'),
  list(targets = 2, className = 'dt-right', searchable = FALSE)
   )),rownames = FALSE, 
filter = 'bottom')
```